# mouse click somewhere else on page (not on a specific div)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to close a little pop-up box in page when user has clicked anywhere on the page other than box area. how to find it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
$(document.body).click(function(e){
   var $box = $('#little-pop-up-box-id');
   if(e.target.id !== 'little-pop-up-box-id' && !$.contains($box[0], e.target))
      $box.remove();
});
```

`e.target` is the `DOM node` which received the `click event`. I'm checking first if the `ID` of that element is **not** the one we are looking for.

The second check `!$.contains($box[0], e.target)` makes sure, that the `DOM node of invocation` is not **within** the element we want to hide.

Well, I guess it's plugin time! :

```
(function($){
   $.fn.outside = function(ename, cb){
      return this.each(function(){
         var $this = $(this),
              self = this;
         $(document.body).bind(ename, function tempo(e){
             if(e.target !== self && !$.contains(self, e.target)){
                cb.apply(self, [e]);
                if(!self.parentNode) $(document.body).unbind(ename, tempo);
             }
         });
      });
   };
}(jQuery));
```

**synopsis**

```
$('#container').outside('click', function(e){
    $(this).remove();
});
```

**Example:**

http://www.jsfiddle.net/qbDKN/30/

Comment: This is a good solution - just two quick comments though.  It would probably make sense to cache the $box var outside of the click handler to avoid re-querying (albeit a cheap query). And if you're using a 1.3.2+ version of jQuery, !$(e.target).closest('#little-pop-up-box-id').length would make a more concise conditional. /nitpicking

Comment: ACHHHH!! TEH CHAIN - IT'S BROKEN! (otherwise... sweetness, +1).
Also... should the 'click' literal be replaced with the ename var?

Comment: @jmar777: right, fixed that :p. I also added an `.unbind()`.. Well I guess this can be optimized at several places. Maybe even a good idea to use `.delegate()`. Who the f**k needs Ben Alman? :) j/k

Comment: @jAndy - good call on using "self" for the apply. Definitely stays more consistent with the other event registration methods. For the "outside" condition, perhaps (e.target !== self) would be better than checking the ID's, since that'll work when ID's aren't present.

Comment: @jmar777: nice one, changed that.

Comment: @coure06: well, the code above works fine (see the example link). Can you provider your code?

Comment: I dont get the line:  if(!self.parentNode) $(document.body).unbind(ename, tempo);

Comment: ah I get it -since you remove the element, you check whether you can unbind the event handler. Eventually you should parameterize that

Comment: Works OK when remove: (function($){ .. }(jQuery)); and add into: $(document).ready(function() {

Answer (score 4):

@jAndy's solution is good, but I wanted to mention [Ben Alman's "Outside Events" plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-outside-events-plugin/) as well.  Here's a quick example using it:

```
$("#popup").bind("clickoutside", function(event){
  $(this).hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("html").click(function(){
//close popup
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Grab global click event, or setup transparent div 100%/100% under the pop-up box with such event.