# OffClick() Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, label

So I have this contact form and I want to put text inside each input, when the user clicks on it the text disappears so they can add stuff - when the user clicks on something else it reappears. I have done this with labels and negative margin along with position relative. I plan on adding an onclick function to each input.

My question is - is there a function that is like Offclick()? Or something similiar to mouseOver() and MouseOut()?

Comment: possible duplicate of [mouse click somewhere else on page (not on a specific div)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3440022/mouse-click-somewhere-else-on-page-not-on-a-specific-div)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Text inputs have `onblur` and select boxes have `onchange` events that can be wired into.

```
<input type="text" id="UserName" name="UserName" value="Placeholder ..." />

<script type="text/javascript">
var el = document.getElementById("UserName");
var original_text = el.value;
el.onblur = function() {
    // `this` is set to the input element by the browser
    if ( ! this.value ) {
        this.value = original_text;
    }
};
</script>
```

With jQuery, it is even easier:

```
var el = $("#UserName");
var original_text = el.val();
el.blur(function(){
    // `this` is set to the input element by jQuery.
    if ( ! this.value ) {
        this.value = original_text;
    }
 });
```

Comment: So I can do the add text with the onblur() function probably instead of labels and margins huh?

Comment: @Howdy_McGee - absolutely.  And if you want to, you can use the HTML5 `placeholder` attribute to get the effect without any JavaScript in supported browsers. http://caniuse.com/#search=placeholder

Comment: Well with HTML5 I run the IE8 problem :(    - One day i'll be able to use HTML5 effectively xD

Answer (score 0):

set title attribute same as value for textboxes and then write:

```
$("input[type=text]").bind("focus",function(){
var $this = $(this);
if($this.attr("title") ==$this.val()){
$this.val('');
}).bind("blur",function(){

var $this = $(this);
if($this.val() ==''){
$this.val($this.attr("title"));
});
```

or you could use a ready made solution like :
http://code.google.com/p/jquery-watermark/